# Emulator not found in AOSP build directory

Tags: android, android-emulator

I downloaded the AOSP source of Lollipop and followed the commands below  to build the source .

```
 source build/envsetup.sh
 lunch aosp_arm-eng
 make -j4
```

It compiled sucessfully withot any errors . I typed emulator in the terminal but it displayed

```
emulator: WARNING: system partition size adjusted to match image file (550 MB > 200 MB)
emulator: WARNING: data partition size adjusted to match image file (550 MB > 200 MB)
SDL init failure, reason is: No available video device
```

I tried to browse for  the emulator fules,but under out/host/linux-86/bin there are no files named emulator . Am using ubuntu 14 64 bit .Is it possible to download the emulator from any other source .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The emulator binaries are under prebuilts/android-emulator/ now.

The WARNINGS are pretty harmless, really. On the other hand, SDL could not initialize, probably because you don't have DISPLAY defined in your environment. I assume this is a headless server or VM you're testing under.

Try using the -no-window flag to start without a window.